# Why, when I install npm-package globally, it doesn't install all of the package dependencies, but it does when I do it locally?

Tags: npm, cypress

I installed `@percy/cypress` package globally and linked it to the project via `npm link`, but there's `@percy/agent` dependency in the `package.json`, and <strike>it's not installed</strike>. I was wrong, namely, it's installed, but the binary from it cannot be found by the system. So I have no binary by `percy`, which I get when `@percy/cypress` is installed locally (through usual `npm install`). Why?

## UPDATE

[My `npm ls -g`](https://pastebin.com/5ixusuBc)

It presents inside `@percy/cypress` package, but there're no environment's paths to its binary, i.e., if i run `percy exec -- cypress run ...`, I get the error:

> sh: 1: percy: not found
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT

And that's not the case when I install it locally or manually add `@percy/agent` as global.

Can I avoid manual installation dependencies of the global package? AFAIK, during local installation npm adds binaries to project's `node_modules/.bin` directory. Maybe, I should provide it too, as (sym)linking to global's or projects binaries' path? A harsh way is just copying necessary directory (`bin`) of `@pecy/agent` to project's `node_modules/.bin`, but it looks strange and tricky. I guess, there should be more appropriate or standard way to make it work

Comment: please provide the output of `npm ls -g`

Comment: @Mr., I amended the post with the output

Comment: share the same as a text without piping to grep

Comment: @Mr. https://pastebin.com/5ixusuBc

Comment: when looking at the file you shared in the comments, i see that the `@percy/agent` is installed locally and globally.

Comment: Yes, but its binary cannot be found by the system, since it's nested. Symlinks to binaries are usually created for top-level packages